# How to read value in JSP to java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

the questions is How can i use id from servlet for use in delete submit(delete submit dont have a id input text when execute always errors 500 cause in delete cant see id )

[image: I got first.jsp like this and send EmpID to removeEmployee (servlet)]
[image: and this is my removeEmp.class if User press Submit it will be redirect to comfirm.jsp or press Delete it will be]
[image: if press submit it's show ID,NAME,Salary that i get it from DB by EmpID in 1st pic]

Comment: mmmm picture parsing, please add the code as code to the question. You might want to pay this page a visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I guess you can use a hidden filed for the id, but html is not my ballpark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did when I was working with jsp and servlets is passing a hidden id inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="employeeId" value="// write value here//" />
```

With this you'll be able to recover it with request.getParam...

Comment: okay , next Question is How i put req.getAttribute() to value in hidden input